# Databinding both activity and recyclerview

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview

I want to databind both the activity and the recyclerview. 
But I get this error for the recycler view. 
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Removing the code for activity data binding, the recyclerview works.

**Activity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IActivity {


    private lateinit var mIMainPresenter: IPresenter
    private lateinit var mMainAdapter: MainAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mIMainPresenter = MainPresenter(this)
        mIMainPresenter.getList()
    }

    /**
     * setup UI widgets
     */
    private fun setupList() {
        val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        mMainAdapter = MainAdapter(mIMainPresenter)
        recyclerList.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
        recyclerList.adapter = mMainAdapter
        recyclerList.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, VERTICAL))
        refresh_layout.setOnRefreshListener {
            fetch(null)
            refresh_layout.isRefreshing = false
        }
    }

    /**
     * fetches list from
     */
    override fun fetch(view: View?) {
        mIMainPresenter.getList()
    }

    /**
     * sets the list items once data is fetched from network/database
     */
    override fun setEvents(result: List<Events>) {
        setupList()
        mMainAdapter.setList(result)
        mMainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun setPrompts(result: List<Prompts>) {
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
               this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.prompt = result[0]
    }

}
```

**Adapter.kt**

```
class MainAdapter(private val mIClick: IClick) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.AutoViewHolder>() {

    private var events: List<Events> = listOf()


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AutoViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ListMainBinding>(inflater, R.layout.list_main, parent, false)
        return AutoViewHolder(binding)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AutoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val event = events.get(position)
        val binding = holder.listMainBinding;
        binding?.events = event
        binding?.iClick = mIClick
        binding?.executePendingBindings()

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return events.size
    }

    fun setList(result: List<Events>) {
        events = result
    }

    inner class AutoViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        var listMainBinding: ListMainBinding? = null

        constructor(binding: ListMainBinding?) : super(binding?.root) {
            listMainBinding = binding
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If setPrompts is called after setEvents, I'm pretty sure it will have created a new RecyclerView and setupList won't be called after that new recycler view is created. That means the new recycler won't have an adapter.

What you will want to do instead is do the setContentView stuff inside of onCreate, keep a reference to the Binding, and then set prompt on that binding when you get the data from the db or network. You will probably also want to do similar with setEvents, and move the initial list setup into onCreate, and just change out the data when that comes in.